# Any one had Logging interceptor for JSF 2.0 Managed bean working

Tags: spring, jsf-2, cdi, interceptor, managed-bean

I have a managed bean with lots of methods. I want to log the entry and exit times of each method invocation . I thought of reusing the Interceptor that works successfully with my EJB's.

I am having no luck with it and interceptor isn't getting called. Is @Interceptors not applicable in managed beans ?

Cheers,
Goutham

Comment: What about using @aop to do the testing?

Comment: No, this is a pure Java EE 6 app, I donot want to add spring just for this.

Comment: Found a way to do it but uses CDI, reading through the blogs I am getting a feeling this is not possible in pure JSF 2.0 environment. Please find the link below: http://blog.arungupta.me/2010/05/totd-134-interceptors-1-1-in-java-ee-6-what-and-how/

Comment: what environment are you in that you have JSF2.0 and not CDI? just curious.

Comment: I understand what you mean :-) I just did not want to rewrite server side code using CDI instead of jsf managed beans.. back then